# Dismiss modal view cause CALayer retainCount sent to deallocated

Tags: ios, memory-management, modalviewcontroller, dismiss, retaincount

In my app, I use method `[self DismissModalView...]` to dismiss a search view, everything was ok in iOS 3 and iOS 4, but now I upgraded to XCode 4.2 and SDK 5, this method runs ok againts iOS 5 but when I test it against iOS 3 + 4, the application crashes with message log:

```
[CALayer retainCount]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xc640b80.
```

I tried to investigate but still not find out root cause, please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are deallocating some view that you didn't retain, autoreleased or something similar. Can't help more without code.

Comment: Everything is ok in XCode 4 and SDk 4.3, I can run app on iOS 4 + 3 without this exception, but after migrating to XCode 4.2 and SDK 5, it is just work on iOS 5, exception just appear when I test app against iOS 4/3.

Comment: Did you find the answer to resolve your problem ? Because we have the same issue. We investigated but with no success. Your help will be very appreciated